# Change active state in a list using useState

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

**Component**

Here is an example of code. What I want is to toggle the active state ( true / false) for each individual list item when I clicked it. I don't want to change them all at once.

Any help with this? Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState({});

  const items = [
   { name: 'Item 1' },
   { name: 'Item 2' },
   { name: 'Item 3' }
  ];

  handleClick = (index) => {
    ...
  }

  const list = items.map( (item, index) => {
    return(
      <li 
        key={index} 
        onClick={() => handleClick(index)} 
        className={active ? "active" : null}
     >
        {item.name}
     </li>
    )
  })

  return {
   <>
    <ul>{list}</ul>
   </>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

**First option - Introducing `isActive` property for each elements**

I would introduce in the `items` an `active` property for each item and manipulate them based on the clicked item. Which needs to be added to `useState` where you can update the `isActive` property with `.map()`.

Similarly like the following:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
   { name: 'Item 1', isActive: true },
   { name: 'Item 2', isActive: false },
   { name: 'Item 3', isActive: false }
]);

handleClick = (index) => {
   setItems(prevItems => 
      prevItems.map((e, i) => ({...e, isActive: i === index}))
   );
}

const list = items.map( (item, index) => {
    return(
      <li 
        key={index} 
        onClick={() => handleClick(index)} 
        className={item.isActive ? 'active' : null}
      >
         {item.name}
      </li>
    )
})

return {
   <>
    <ul>{list}</ul>
   </>
}
```

**Second option - store the `index` for the clicked active element**

Storing the `index` for the clicked element helps you the identify in `.map()` which one is the active one. So with a simple check with `i === index` you can add `active` class to the `<li>` element.

You can create a state for `index` with `useState` as the following:

```
const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

const items = [
   { name: 'Item 1' },
   { name: 'Item 2' },
   { name: 'Item 3' }
];

handleClick = (i) => {
   setIndex(i);
}

const list = items.map( (item, i) => {
    return(
      <li 
        key={i} 
        onClick={() => handleClick(i)} 
        className={i === index ? 'active' : null}
      >
         {item.name}
      </li>
    )
})

return {
   <>
    <ul>{list}</ul>
   </>
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want to introduce an active property in each item

Comment: @DariusD Just extended with a second option my answer. Storing the index of the clicked element, instead of introducing new field in the array.

Comment: Good so far but how can I toggle it? or having multiple actives at once ? For example item-1 and item-3

Comment: @DariusD In that case I would go with the first option but with a modification of toggling `isActive` property. +1: I have a git repo for toggle items on click, might be interesting: https://github.com/norbitrial/react-toogle-class-on-click

Comment: first option is not good for me, but it's ok i'll try something else anyway

Answer (score 1):

Added comments inline.

```
const App = () => {
  // active is active item, initially '' means, nothing selected.
  const [active, setActive] = useState("");

  const items = [{ name: "Item 1" }, { name: "Item 2" }, { name: "Item 3" }];

  const list = items.map(({ name }) => (
    <li
      key={name /* avoid using index for key */}
      onClick={() => setActive(name)}
      className={active === name ? "active" : ""}
    >
      {name}
    </li>
  ));

  // return the Element, not {}
  return (
    <>
      <ul>{list}</ul>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```